# CKEditor auto-formats (screws up) HTML5 tags

Tags: html, web, ckeditor

I'm trying to paste a simple piece of HTML into the HTML editor

```
<video class="videofile" controls="controls" height="272" poster="poster.jpg" preload="none" tabindex="0" width="480"> 
    <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4" /> 
    <source src="video.webm" type="video/webm" />  
</video>
```

However, when I go back to WYSIWYG, it auto-formats it as such:

```
<p><video class="videofile" controls="controls" height="272" poster="poster.jpg" preload="none" tabindex="0" width="480"> <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4"> <source src="video.webm" type="video/webm"> </source></source></video></p>
```

It's completely screwed up (note the  tags). How can I disable this? I've tried setting config.FormatOutput and config.AutoParagraph to be false. Thanks.

Comment: I have the same problem in CkEditor 4.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could never find an answer for this issue. I ended up allowing a raw TEXTAREA editor for code entry. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this plugin http://alfonsoml.blogspot.com/2011/01/html5-video-plugin-for-ckeditor.html and that way you don't have to paste anything in source mode and the HTML will remain valid.

Comment: I don't want to add new plugins, I want to disable a feature built in to the editor.

Answer (score 0):

CKEditor 3.6.1 supposedly doesn't improperly mess with HTML5 tags. Can you upgrade?

Comment: I upgraded to 3.6.2. Do I need to revert to an old version?

Comment: I wouldn't expect so. But you hadn't said what version you were running, so figured it was worth a shot in case you were on something older.